# Matplotlib surface color not solid

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting a plane in Matplotlib, I do not get a solid color. I get the following with many shades of red:

[image: Not red plane]

I am using Matplotlib version 1.5.1 in Python 3.5.2. The code that I'm running is below:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xaxis = np.linspace(-3, 3, 201)
yaxis = np.linspace(-3, 3, 201)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xaxis, yaxis)

Z = 8 - 3*X - 3*Y
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,color='r')

plt.savefig('not_red.png')
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the view? I get a different result when run on my machine using 3.6.2 some darker spots but not as much

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing the view. That does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want any shading the solution is to set `shade=False`:

```
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,color='r', shade=False)
```

Source: [Matplotlib Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)